# Existence of bump functions which are positive on a prescribed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, manifolds

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open subset of Euclidean space.  I feel like there should be a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f|_U > 0$ and $f|_{\mathbb{R}^n\setminus U} \equiv 0$.  Probably one way to show this is to role up your sleeves and try to generalize the proof of paracompactness of manifolds by showing that you can refine to a locally finite cover containing a subset whose union is $U$. After trying to do that for a while, I thought I'd ask if anyone can think of a nicer way to do it.  Maybe using a convolution or by applying the standard para compactness result in a clever way.  I noticed that distance to the boundary gives a continuous version. Maybe it can be smoothed somehow?  I am particularly interested in the case where $U$ is star-shaped, if that's needed (I couldn't imagine why it would be). However, please don't use the result that star-shaped oped sets are diffeomorphic to Euclidean space because that's what I'm trying to prove :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can use convolution. Take $V_n = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n : \text{dist}(x,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus U)>\frac{1}{n} \}$

Then take

$f_n(x)  = \frac{1}{2^n}(\chi_{V_n} * \Phi_n)(x)$

where $\Phi_n(x) = \Phi(n x)$

and $\Phi$ is a bump function that is positive on the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. (For example, we may set $\Psi(a)=\exp(-\frac{1}{1-a^2})$ for $-1<a<1$ and $\Psi(a)=0$ otherwise, and then define $\Phi(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\Psi(x_1)\dots\Psi(x_n)$.)

And the function you look for should be:

$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks, Tom.

Comment: This might be a silly question but what's the best way to verify smoothness of that sum?

Comment: Oh I see. All of the derivatives satisfy the Weierstrass M-test