# Existence of smooth function with given compact support

Tags: general-topology, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $K$ be a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Does there exist a smooth function $\phi$ such that $0<\phi\leq 1$ on $K$ and 0 outside of $K$

Comment: Also, given your current hypotheses $\phi \equiv 0$ works.

Comment: I believe what you wanted to know is that if $U$ is open, $K$ is compact, $U \subset K$, then there exists a $C^\infty$ function $phi$ that is $1$ on $U$ and $0$ outside $K$.

Comment: I just edited the question. I want the function to be strictly positive on $K$

Comment: @ Feanor : I would be interested in such $\phi$. Can you prove its existence or construct it?

Comment: I think this might be what you want: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290421/existence-of-bump-functions-which-are-positive-on-a-prescribed-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I speculate that what you say you want is not what you do really want. Tweaking Feanor's comment in a direction that makes sense to me for various applications I've seen, I'd think you'd want, for example, a smooth function $\varphi$ identically $1$ on a given compact $K$, and identically $0$ outside a given open $U\supset K$. *This* is possible, because there is room to "smooth" any corners or rough edges of $K$ a little inside $U$... there are widely-accessible discussions of "smooth partitions of unity subordinate to locally finite covers" that carry out relevant discussions.

Answer (score 1):

You would then have $K = \varphi^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{*}_{+})$ open, since $\varphi$ is be continuous. And this cannot happen since no proper and nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are both open and closed.